# Safe Navigator using in Iqueryable conditional clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

ObjectA is Entity in EF. 
Here I try to check is there any record in DB table with match ObjectA Bid Property of giving ObjectB.

Problem is if ObjectB is null then which return null and check against null. So in that case Do i want to check objectB is null before this?

```
var result = ObjectA.Any(i => i.Bid == ObjectB?.Id);
```

Comment: So what are you exactly asking?

Comment: I felt like using safe navigation property on these kind of condition would be problematic. people easily used it to avoid null reference exception but here it gave me some unexpected result because it return null if left side is null

Comment: Ah like that I understand

Answer (score 1):

You can check if null first using the tertiary conditional operator, syntax: `Cond?ReturnIfTrue:ReturnIfFalse`

```
var result = ObjectB!=null?ObjectA.Any(i=>i.Bid == ObjectB.Id):null;
```